# How to replace many json values in whole table in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plsql

Here is input data:
We have table with "data" - json-type column
Also we have table with "oldUrl", "newUrl" columns - which is mapping from oldUrl to newUrl
What we want:
Search for oldUrl in all "data" records and replace every oldUrl with newUrl;
What is the most perfomant way to solve this, any ideas?

Here is first thing that came to my mind:

```
do
$$DECLARE 
    datarec record;
    urlrec record;
    tempdata text;
BEGIN 
 FOR datarec IN SELECT id, data FROM datatable LOOP
    tempdata := datarec.data::text;
    FOR urlrec IN SELECT oldUrl, newUrl FROM urlsmap LOOP 
        tempdata := replace(tempdata, urlrec.oldUrl, urlrec.newUrl)
    END LOOP;
    UPDATE datatable
    SET data = tempdata::json
    WHERE id = datarec.id
 END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

But as I noticed that it would take forever to process;
Is there better way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with a pure sql code, it should be faster :

```
UPDATE datatable AS d
   SET data = replace(d.data :: text, quote_ident(m.oldUrl), quote_ident(m.newUrl)) -- quote_ident() automatically adds double quotes so that to search for the exact oldUrl substring
  FROM urlsmap AS m
 WHERE d.data :: text ~ m.oldUrl -- condition to select and update only the rigth rows in table datatable
```

In order to accelerate even more your query you can first index the `data` column with the `GIN` index (resp. `GiST` index) and the associated operator class `gin_trgm_ops` (resp. `gist_trgm_ops`) :

```
CREATE INDEX gin_data ON datatable (data :: text gin_trgm_ops );
```